# Nodejs Shortid on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to use the shortid module from npm to generate unique URLs in an application running at AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The documentation says that a unique worker id should be set for each instance of node.js using shortid to guarantee uniqueness. Is there any simple way to assign ids between 0 to N to the EB instances?

The only solution I could think of so far is to use DynamoDB to store the list of running instances or a list of available ids and update as new node.js servers are launched/killed, but it seems to me there must be a simpler way to do this, is there? Couldn't find much information about this so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply roll a random number and use it. AFAIK the worker numbers doesn't have to be consecutive, just unique.
Alternatively, you can use the ec2 instance-id. Though undocumented, the following will get you the instance-id of the current machine:
`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

Comment: Still doesn't guarantee their uniqueness though, just makes it less likely to coincide. Also, they say the worker number should optimally be less than 16, so quite a big chance of collision with even just a couple workers. I hoped AWS has some info like this hidden somewhere :/

Comment: @laky, how can a random number miss your goal. just roll a number between 0 and UINT_MAX. The chances of getting the same numbers are negligible. still, I've updated my answer with a `hidden` info per your request :/